# Laravel site cannot be accessed by domain but can be by LocalHost:8000

Tags: php, laravel, command, vagrant, homestead

I am fairly new to web programming and have come into a tough problem. In the past I would be able to access a larvel site by running the command "vagrant up" in the homestead folder and then using the site name that I indicated in the "Homestead.yaml" file.

Recently I updated my Mac to the latest version of High Sierra. I do not know if this is the main culprit, but for some reason now I am unable to reach the site by using the domain. I am however able to reach the laravel home page by going to localhost:8000.

here is a list of things that I have done trying to fix the issue:

- I have tried uninstalling virtual box, homestead, and vagrant and reinstalling them but that has not fixed the issue.
- I tried running vagrant -provisions but that did not help the situation

Here are my files:

Homestead.yaml

---

```
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/Code
      to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
    - map: hoomestead1.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/Project1/public
    - map: lxa.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/lxa/public
    - map: beerstreet.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/beerstreet/public
    - map: blackbook.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/blackbook/public

databases:
    - homestead

# blackfire:
#     - id: foo
#       token: bar
#       client-id: foo
#       client-token: bar

# ports:
#     - send: 50000
#       to: 5000
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp
```

Host Files

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost

192.168.10.10  homestead.app
192.168.10.10  hoomestead1.app
192.168.10.10  lxa.app
192.168.10.10  beerstreet.app
192.168.10.10  blackbook.app
```

I really have no clue what the problem could be. It was working fine a day ago and now will not work. Can anyone please give me a suggestion on things I haven't tried yet and should?

Answer (score 0):

Your host entry for the name you want needs to point at `127.0.0.1`, as that's what `localhost` resolves to.

The hosts file should include a mapping like this, if the name you are using is `homestead.app`:

```
127.0.0.1    homestead.app
```

`127.0.0.1` is what's called the loopback ip. It is the ip address that always maps to your own computer. You should use this for any names you need to point locally.

Comment: Hi there, could you please explain a little more? Are you saying that "127.0.0.1" is what all the IP addresses for my domains should be? Thank you!

Comment: Does that clarify things?

Comment: Yes it does! Thank you! I did what you said but it still didn't work. Is it possibly a High Sierra issue?

Comment: You'll still need to specify the port... like `http://homestead.app:8000`

Comment: I did that as well! But I would prefer to be able to access it through just http://homestead.ap, which is why I went with the 192.168.10.10 route. Is it possible a DNS issue?

Comment: the hosts file is consulted before talking to your dns server. think of it as static dns overrides. you need to specify the port because the default port for http is 80, and it is being hosted on an alternate port to avoid configuration conflicts with the host machine

Comment: I decided to uninstall/reinstall again and followed all the directions in the [larval documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/homestead) including the mapping and am still not getting anything.